# Is it possible to call functions in one executable from another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have two executables - one GUI, one command line.  I want to be able to call functions in one from the other.  Ordinarily I would refactor out the common code to a static library so it's accessible from both, but I can't do that in this instance (due to problems with some of VS2008's code auto-generation for database bindings).

I assume that this must be possible in some way as the unit test applications use this mechanism.  How do you do this in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple -- add a reference to the assembly you want to call into from the other.  If both assemblies are built in the same solution, just use a project reference.  Obviously you can't call both assemblies from the other, since this would create a circular reference.

Comment: Its certainly possible to create circular references. Start with assembly A, compile it. Create assembly B, referencing A, compile. Now add a reference to B in A, recompile A. Circular reference created.

Comment: Excellent - simpler than I thought!